# Langton's Ant cellular automaton in Ruby

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, cellular-automata

I wrote a Langton's Ant cellular automaton simulator in Ruby using object oriented principles. This code works. It requires the `drawille` library.

I would like to get feedback on what I could do better here, from optimizing the display to cleaning up code. I'm also wondering what I could improve in code quality and style.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'drawille'

# Langton's Ant
# Draws in terminal

class Direction
    @dir = 0

    def initialize(direction)
        @dir = {up: 0, right: 1, down: 2, left: 3}[direction] || 0;
    end

    def transform_vector
        case @dir
        when 0
            return {x: 0, y: 1}
        when 1
            return {x: 1, y: 0}
        when 2
            return {x: 0, y: -1}
        when 3
            return {x: -1, y: 0}
        end
    end

    def turn_cw
        @dir = (@dir + 1) % 4
    end

    def turn_ccw
        @dir = (@dir + 3) % 4
    end
end

module State
    OFF = 0
    ON = 1
end

class Tile
    @state = State::OFF
    def initialize(state)
        @state = state
    end
    def state
        return @state
    end
    def flip
        if @state == State::OFF
            return @state = State::ON
        else
            return @state = State::OFF
        end
    end
    def bool
        return (@state == State::ON ? true : false)
    end
end

class Screen
    @screen = [];
    @canvas = Drawille::Canvas.new
    @x = 0
    @y = 0

    def initialize(x, y)
        @screen = Array.new(y) { Array.new(x) { Tile.new State::OFF } }
        @canvas = Drawille::Canvas.new
        @x = x
        @y = y
    end

    def inspect
        string = "";
        @screen.each do |i|
            i.each do |j|
                string << (j.bool ? '██' : '  ')
            end
            string << ?\n
        end
        return string
    end

    def screen
        return @screen
    end

    def flip(x, y)
        return @screen[y][x].flip
    end

    def print
        @screen.each_with_index do |row, y|
            row.each_with_index do |cell, x|
                if cell.state == State::ON
                    @canvas.set(x, y)
                else
                    @canvas.unset(x, y)
                end
            end
        end
        puts @canvas.frame
    end

    def x
        @x
    end

    def y
        @y
    end
end

class Ant
    @x = 0
    @y = 0
    @direction = :up
    @screen = nil

    def initialize(x, y, direction, screen)
        @x, @y, @direction, @screen = x, y, direction, screen
    end

    def current_cell
        @screen.screen[@y][@x]
    end

    def step
        if current_cell.state == State::ON
            @direction.turn_cw
        else
            @direction.turn_ccw
        end
        @screen.flip(@x, @y)
        @x = (@x + @direction.transform_vector[:x]) % @screen.x
        @y = (@y + @direction.transform_vector[:y]) % @screen.y
    end
end

def main
    screen = Screen.new(160, 96);
    ant = Ant.new(79, 47, Direction.new(:down), screen);

    loop do
        screen.print
        ant.step
    end
end

main
```

Comment: The `Tile` class and its collaborators go to a lot of effort to make `0` and `1` act like booleans. Why not just use `false` and `true`?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Langton's Ant has variants that are more interesting - they require a tile having multiple types, so I wrote the class for extensibility purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks pretty clean. On first sight I notice some odd Ruby code.

### Non-idiomatic Ruby

```
class Tile
    @state = State::OFF
    def initialize(state)
        @state = state
    end
    def state
        return @state
    end
    def flip
        if @state == State::OFF
            return @state = State::ON
        else
            return @state = State::OFF
        end
    end
    def bool
        return (@state == State::ON ? true : false)
    end
end
```

In the code above you first set `@state` and then inside `initialize` you set `@state` again. These two are not the same variable. Do not define instance variables outside class methods, unless you want to do some meta-programming with them.

You define method `state` for accessing the `@state` variable. As this is such a common pattern, Ruby provides a helper for generating such simpler getter methods:

```
class Tile
    attr_accessor :state
```

But all the places where `state` method is used, could actually use the `bool` method instead. This should make one realize that this whole Tile class could be completely eliminated and replaced with a plain boolean value instead.

### Other smells

- Screen class has `@screen` instance variable. It's not referring to itself, so a better name would be in order.
- It's also exposing it directly to the outside world through `screen` method. Better to have a method like `get(x,y)` that would encapsulate the access to the coordinates array.
- Screen has an `inspect` method that's unused. For debugging?
- Screen has `x` and `y` fields, I think these are better called `width` and `height`.
- Screen has a `print` method. I would instead recommend having a `to_s` method instead, so the Screen would not have a knowledge about printing itself, only of how to convert itself into string. One can then simply call `puts screen` to print it to console (the `to_s` method will be call automatically when casting to string).
- Inside `Ant.initialize` all the variables are initialize on the same line, which I find confusing.

Comment: I have the `Tile` class for future extension (in case I want to implement some Langton's Ant variants). The `bool` method is one that I forgot to remove.  I used `Screen#inspect` for output before I switched to `drawille`.  Thanks for the tips on `attr_accessor`, field names, instance variables, `to_s`, etc. I find the one line initialization cleaner and easier to read, but if it's confusing for most people I'll change it.